# VLOOKUP Multiple Columns If Not Found In First Column

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a long list of part numbers where I need to be able to lookup and retrieve information on them.
These parts can have several alternative part numbers. I have figured out how to get the data returned if my data table only shows one of the possibly part numbers. 
The issue is that I want it to be able to look up the columns to find a matching value.

As in the picture below for example. 5-E26 is the equivalent to E5-25. So if I input 5-E26 in the cell, I want it to continue searching to find the value in B7, and return the data as done A4 and A5.

Is this possible to do with Vlookup? Or is there a smarter method for it?

[image: Only One part number included]

[image: Returns value of row 4 and 5 perfectly]

[image: Alternativepartnumbers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggle to fully understand how your data works but here is a possibility:

[image]

So the translated version of the formula I used in `G2`:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$5,AGGREGATE(15,3,((($A$2:$D$5=F2)/($A$2:$D$5=F2))*ROW($A$2:$A$5)),1))
```

You could also try (in my case):

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$5,SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$D$5=F2)*ROW($A$2:$D$5)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm!  
After I scaled it up another problem has revealed itself though. I have a total of more than 10.000 rows, and some of these part numbers occur several times. I am not sure if this is what's causing the issue, but I think it's likely, as I have tried to exclude the line where it occurs again, and it solves it.

For example in row 1201, Part E-E25 occurs in the column in Part#3, and here it returns something completely unrelated
There will be many cases where this happens. Is there perhaps any way to force it to return the first value it finds?

Comment: The first formula I showed should solve that since it only return the smallest found value (row index number) where the searchvalue matches.

Comment: It absolutely did. Thanks for your help, this is gonna save me countless of hours!